# Не могу создать executable JAR-архив

Tags: java, jar, javac

Пытаюсь поподробнее разобраться с ручной компиляцией java-проектов и появилась задача создать простой выполняемый jar-архив.
Имеется файл:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello there! I am executable JAR!");
    }
}
```

Выполняю следующий операции в терминале:

```
vladislav@...:~/work$ javac -d bin src/stackoverflow/Question.java 
vladislav@...:~/work$ jar cvfe question.jar stackoverflow.Question bin
added manifest
adding: bin/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: bin/stackoverflow/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: bin/stackoverflow/Question.class(in = 457) (out= 320)(deflated 29%)
vladislav@...:~/work$ java -jar question.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class stackoverflow.Question
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Работаю на ubuntu 16.04 LTS;

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jar cvfe question.jar stackoverflow.Question -C bin .
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает!